# For Uber Development API, Is it possible to pass source and destination address as parameters to get cost estimation response

Tags: uber-api

For Uber ride requests, it requires start location(start Geo Location), end location(end Geo Location) and fair Id.

As from user perspective, i can pass source and destination address.
Is it possible to pass start and end location as address which is given by the user or needs to manually convert the address as geo location using any google api's.

the third parameter fair Id, where should i find the fair id?

I have read the [developer.uber.com document](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post), for start location and end location, geo locations are mandatory and start and end address are optional.

Kindly assist to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? If you just need cost estimate you should probably use https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get

Fare ID is if you are going to be proceeding to call a ride for a user with the privileged 'request' scope.

Comment: Thanks for reply Kyle Davis. Actually my doubt is, should i need to convert the source and destination address as geo-location or can directly pass the address.

Answer (score 0):

For version v1.2, you must pass the latitude and longitude of the place. The best solution is to use another api to get the latitude/longitude of a place then send the lat/longitude to thje uber api. There are a few free lat/longitude apis out there, such as google location api.

Answering this for others who may look for this in the future, since I had same question a few weeks ago.